# Calculating Interest Rate

Tags: c++

So I am trying to learn C++ for a college course and I have to write a program which uses this formula:

```
Amount = Principal * (1 + Rate/T)^T
```

Where principal is the balance in savings, rate is the interest rate, and t is the number of times the interest is compounded during a year. According to the book if you type in 4.25 as the interest rate and 12 as the number of times compounded with the principal as 1000.00 then you should get 43.34 as interest and the total amount should be 1043.34. I'm not sure if I am coding it wrong or what but I was wondering if anyone could help me out with any mistakes I might have done! I'm trying to do it on my own for about a day or two now but I have had no luck.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    double PRINCIPAL;
    double INTEREST_RATE;
    double COMPOUND_AMOUNT;


    cout << "What is your savings account balance?: " << endl;
    cin >> PRINCIPAL;
    cout << "What is your annual interest rate?: " << endl;
    cin >> INTEREST_RATE;
    cout << "How many times has your interest been compounded?: " << endl;
    cin >> COMPOUND_AMOUNT;

    double amt1 = 1 + (INTEREST_RATE/COMPOUND_AMOUNT);
    double AMOUNT = PRINCIPAL * pow(amt1, COMPOUND_AMOUNT);

    cout << "Interest Rate: " << INTEREST_RATE << endl;
    cout << "Times Compounded: " << COMPOUND_AMOUNT << endl;
    cout << "Principal: " << PRINCIPAL << endl;
    cout << "Interest: " << INTEREST_RATE * COMPOUND_AMOUNT << endl;
    cout << "Amount: " << AMOUNT << endl;

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What problems do you have with the code? And for the input you give in your question, what is the *actual* output?

Comment: So I type in 1000.00 as the principal (account balance).
Then I type in 4.25 as the interest rate. Finally I put 12 as the number of times the interest has been compounded. And I get the interest showing up as 51 and the amount is 38024.7 but in the book it says that it should show up as 43.34 as the interest and the amount should be 1043.34.

Comment: Are you sure the formula is correct? First of all because with a calculator I get the same results you do, and secondly because with an interest rate of 4.25% compounded 12 times you should have a compounded interest of almost 65% (`1.0425` to the power of `12` gives the multiplication factor, subtract one and multiply by 100 to get the percent (`64.783136`)).

Comment: http://prntscr.com/4p0bo4 That has all my code and the input and output of the program when I put in the data. But the book shows the "Amount:" as 1043.34. And the "Interest:" as 43.34. This is so annoying how I feel like I am making a small stupid mistake but I don't know what it is!

Answer (score 1):

This is a math error. If you're going to take in interest rates as '4.25' %, you need to divide the interest rate by 100. The code below gave me the amount as 1043.34 when 4.25 is entered as the interest rate.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    double PRINCIPAL;
    double INTEREST_RATE;
    double COMPOUND_AMOUNT;


    cout << "What is your savings account balance?: " << endl;
    cin >> PRINCIPAL;
    cout << "What is your annual interest rate? (in %): " << endl;
    cin >> INTEREST_RATE;
    INTEREST_RATE /= 100;
    cout << "How many times has your interest been compounded?: " << endl;
    cin >> COMPOUND_AMOUNT;

    double amt1 = 1 + (INTEREST_RATE/COMPOUND_AMOUNT);
    double AMOUNT = PRINCIPAL * pow(amt1, COMPOUND_AMOUNT);

    cout << "Interest Rate (%): " << INTEREST_RATE * 100 << endl;
    cout << "Times Compounded: " << COMPOUND_AMOUNT << endl;
    cout << "Principal ($): " << PRINCIPAL << endl;
    cout << "Interest ($): " << AMOUNT - PRINCIPAL << endl;
    cout << "Amount ($): " << AMOUNT << endl;

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

for interest your book is talking about the amount of interest in dollars, i.e. AMOUNT - PRINCIPAL.

Comment: Oh my god! Thank you so much, you don't know how long I have been sitting here stuck on this! Finally I can move forward! I am incredibly thankful! :)!

Comment: Np the simplest errors are often the hardest to find